# Why is the command not working

Tags: sql, openoffice.org, libreoffice-base

What is wrong with that command I'm trying to use? Why is it not working? I could rage endlessly with hSQL... in combination with openoffice_base (because my employer is a cheap son of a) one day it'll kill me..

Explanation:

- Table Suppliers -> Supp
- Table ContactPerson -> Con
- Table IT_Con_Supp

I want to have a intermediate table because one company can have 0 or many contact-persons and 0 or many contact-persons can belong to one company.

for the love of god - I found this page http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i59x.png

but not a single command is working in base - I assume it's coz base is hsqldb and not sql?

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

with the SQL statement add in:

```
USE 'DATABASE_NAME'
```

then the rest of your query. It might be that you do not have the proper database specifically specified so the query is trying to run against a sys database.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions. 
Zion1 - I didint quite catch what you mean.. 

PS: Zion, it's not a query think more of a create table command.
like:
"CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)"
But for some reason I cant get it to work :(

Comment: Not sure if it is possible but can you go into tools > SQL > command to execute box write the script except using the additional "USE" statement. Open Office is a both awesome and finicky at times.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE "IT_Con_Supp"
ADD FOREIGN KEY("FK_SUPP") REFERENCES "Supp"("ID")
```

I haven't used Office Base much but I believe it works a bit like Postgres in terms of case sensitivity.

Comment: it didnt work out. 
If I copy/paste ur command I get this message:

"1: Column not found: FK_SUPP in statement [ALTER TABLE "IT_Con_Supp"
ADD FOREIGN KEY("FK_SUPP")]"

I'm really frustrated with that issue...

Comment: You will have to type the field name exactly as the case is in the table. I could not know how it was spelt. I just copied your code.